# how to do è on Mac with 67 keys windows keyboard

Tags: keyboard, macbook

I'm on Mac. I have a 65% drop alt mechanical keyboard

[image]

https://drop.com/buy/drop-alt-mechanical-keyboard?defaultSelectionIds=966466%2C966471

How do I type `è` without press and hold?

é <= alt/option keys + e + e

` <= fn key

Answer (score 0):

If Fn generates ` then try Opt/Fn/` then e.

You could have a look in Keyboard viewer, which will show you when the keyboard is about to enter e dead key, eg

[image]

Orange highlighted keys are ready to be dead keys. Backtick is usually left of Z on a UK keyboard, left of 1 on a US keyboard… but as you have neither of those, you'll have to try spot where Fn generates it.